# TinyMCE file upload, generic syntax error

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When using TinyMCE's "Ajax File Manager" plugin file upload, I get the following error when I hit the upload button:

"Syntax error: missing ; before statement"

Everything else seems to be working okay. Any ideas? (Permission settings somewhere maybe?)

EDIT: Here's some more info: If the uploaded folder is left in the original structure there is no problem...
When I move the uploaded folder (and make the appropriate changes to config.base.php) the error occurs. Why would changing the location of the upload folder cause that error?

```
tinymce
|
|   jscripts
    |
    |    tiny_mce
         |
         |   plugins
             |
             |     ajaxfilemanager
             |     |
             |     |     inc
             |           |
             |           |    config.base.php        (the CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_PATH and CONFIG_SYS_ROOT_PATH need to be '../uploaded/')
             |     
             |     uploaded             (chmod to 777 - placement of folder any other place causes errors, even if changed in config.base.php)
```

EDIT: I just learned that the problem started happening when mod_security was added to Apache and recompiled. Has anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: Our host had just added mod_security and recompiled Apache. They had to white list ajaxfilemanager to get it to work properly again.

Answer (score -1):

```
define('CONFIG_SYS_MY_DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . implode('/',array_slice(explode('/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),0,-3)));  
define('CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_PATH', CONFIG_SYS_MY_DOCROOT.'/uploads/'); //accept relative path only
define('CONFIG_SYS_ROOT_PATH', CONFIG_SYS_MY_DOCROOT.'/uploads/');   //accept relative path only

//define('CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_PATH', '../../../uploads/'); //accept relative path only
//define('CONFIG_SYS_ROOT_PATH', '../../../uploads/');  //accept relative path only
```

Comment: what -1 ? please test first !